# Pandas won't open weird TSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The TSV file here
https://www.imf.org/-/media/Files/Publications/WEO/WEO-Database/2022/WEOApr2022all.ashx
which comes from
https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WEO/weo-database/2022/April/download-entire-database
will not open on Pandas. I have tried several things: using a separator for tabs, opening it with read_excel (the website says it's compatible with all modern systems).

import pandas as pd

```
path = "C:..\\WEOApr2022all.xls"

dataframe = pd.read_csv(path, sep="\\t", encoding='windows-1252')
```

Error:     chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
File "pandas_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1960, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 14

Comment: Excel files are binary, not tab-separated text. And obsolete for 16 years, when they were replaced by `xlsx`, a ZIP package containing XML files. You can't any Excel format with `read_csv`.

Comment: Some extremely lazy developers try to fake Excel files by generating a CSV or even HTML table and send it as a file with a fake `.xls` extension. This may fool users, but not Excel itself. Excel will recognize this is a *text* file and try to *import* it using the user's defaults for separators, number and date formats. If those don't match the developer's formats, you'll get errors. If you go to the `Data` menu in Excel, you can use `Import Text` with your own separator and format settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its file extension it is a tab delimited, UTF16 encoded text file and can be read using

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\\t', encoding='utf_16le', engine='python', skipfooter=2)
```

8624 rows × 58 columns

Note: You need to specify the delimiter as a regex (`'\\t`' or `r'\t'`) instead of a single character (`'\t'`) and hence use the `python` engine because each lines ends with a delimiter. If you use `'\t'` you'll get an extra empty column at the end.

Comment: If you use `\t` you won't have to specify `engine='python'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but you don't get the data correctly in this case (extra unnamed column at the end)